# how create a link to local file

Tags: file, hyperlink, local

I would open this link with my browser:

```
file:///sdcard/video.wmv
```

if write it to the address bar, browser opens it.

but if I create a link like this it won't open it:

```
<a href="file:///sdcard/video.wmv">open video</a>
```

thank you

Comment: Besides needing to use the full path, it seems like this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24043568/html-javascript-link-to-a-local-file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [html/javascript link to a local file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24043568/html-javascript-link-to-a-local-file)